# Python mock using existing object but supplying other methods

Tags: python, python-2.7, unit-testing, mocking

I have a class that mostly presents a set of ids, but has other methods. Something like this:

```
class PoundIds(object):
    ....
    @property
    def cats(self):
        return self.cats

    @property
    def dogs(self):
        return self.dogs

    @property
    def animal_ids(self):
        return set(dog.id for dog in self.dogs) | set(cat.id for cat in self.cats)

    def __contains__(self, id):
        return id in self.animal_ids

    def __iter__(self, id):
        return self.animal_ids.__iter__()
```

For a lot of purposes, I could just mock this with `set([1,2,3])`, but not all. If I could create a mock that provided the special methods I need and otherwise passed calls to a set, that would work nicely. Can mock create a mock that is based on an existing object but gives it extra methods? It seems like it should, but I'm at a loss for how I might do that.